# How to save multiple file paths in a txt file for json.load() to read?

Tags: python, json, txt

I have two json files that I'd like to open to read from and instead of calling the open() function twice to open the json files individually, I tried this:

```
with open('./file_paths.txt') as file_list:
    for filename in file_list:
        json_data = json.load(file_list)
```

where in the `'./file_paths.txt'` file I've got two paths listed like this:

```
./dataset_1.json,
./dataset_2.json
```

I have a comma separating them. I tried enclosing them in quotation marks but I'm still getting the same error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

There is a problem with this line:

```
json_data = json.load(file_list)
```

in that I think the problem is how I've listed the filepaths in the .txt file.

Comment: So... `filename` is a string containing a file name while `file_list` is the list of file names. How do you expect `json.load(file_list)` to work? Should be `json.load(filename)` or not? If not, why the loop?

Comment: You are passing the wrong argument to `json.load`, but the commas in your file aren't part of the file names, and will need to be stripped from each argument before passing it to `json.load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the json.load function (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) refers to a *single* file or file-like object:

> `json.load(fp, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)`
>
> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion
> table.

As you seem to want the loaded data from two files combined into one object, the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059974/4438898) looks useful. It creates a 'merge_dict' function that combines two json-derived dictionaries into one, merging the entries where the keys are identical.

**Reading a list of files and loading the json as a list of dicts**

(Added in response to your replies)

This reads lines from `mylistfile.txt` line by line, strips the trailing '\n' from each line, then loads the json data from the resulting filename. The json data is added as a dictionary to the `results` list, and the results are printed:

```
Adding data from dataset_1.json
Adding data from dataset_2.json
Results: [{'hello': 1, 'there': 2}, {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}]
```

`mylistfile.txt` was a 2 line file:

```
dataset_1.json
dataset_2.json
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this question and answer? This is where I got the idea from actually but there is no explanation about how the list of paths in the .txt file is constructed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149972/how-to-open-multiple-file-paths

Comment: Do you mean how to loop over a text file that contains a list of path/file names? That's a little different to your original question. Also, where do you want the contents of each json file to be stored: added to one large dictionary, or added as one item in a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Added as one item in a list of dictionaries. How can I store them in the text file? Comma separated? In strings or not?

Comment: Please see the added section to my answer, above. If it fits the bill then please accept the answer.